# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ (Using hilt and MVVM acrh))

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, dagger-hilt

```
rocess: com.ashish.newswave, PID: 16941
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@54a2eea, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

```
data class News(
    @field:SerializedName("results")
    val results: List<NewsItem?>?,
)

data class NewsItem(

    @field:SerializedName("image_url")
    val imageUrl: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("link")
    val link: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("description")
    val description: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("title")
    val title: String? = null,

)


interface NewsApi {
    @GET("/api/1/news?country=np&apikey=pub_2876097511868cf87f5e2798f773d7e3eab33")
    suspend fun getAllNews():Call<News>
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://newsdata.io")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNewsApi(retrofit: Retrofit):NewsApi{
        return retrofit.create(NewsApi::class.java)
    }
}

class NewsRepository @Inject constructor(private val newsApi: NewsApi) {

    private val _newsItems=MutableStateFlow<List<NewsItem?>>(emptyList())
    val newsItem:StateFlow<List<NewsItem?>>
        get() =_newsItems

    suspend fun getNews(){
        val response=newsApi.getAllNews().execute()
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body()!=null){
            _newsItems.emit(response)
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class NewsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val newsRepository: NewsRepository) :ViewModel() {
    val newsItems: StateFlow<List<NewsItem?>>
        get() =newsRepository.newsItem

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                newsRepository.getNews()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
"status": "success",
"totalResults": 488,
"results": [
{
"article_id": "51c4ba26668a317008c63189f4f4069c",
"title": "कोशी सरकार विवादमा रिट निवेदक पक्षको ५ तर्क",
"link": "https://www.onlinekhabar.com/2023/09/1360979",
"keywords": [
"राष्ट्रिय समाचार",
"कोशी",
"सर्वोच्च अदालत"
],
"creator": [
"Binod Dhakal"
],
"video_url": null,
"description": "१८ भदौ, काठमाडौं । कोशी प्रदेशका मुख्यमन्त्री उद्धव थापाले पाएको विश्वासको मतमाथि उठेको विवादबारे सर्वोच्च अदालतमा सोमबार बहस सुरु भएको छ । विश्वासको मत लिने दिन प्रदेश सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेका इस्राइल मन्सुरीले दिएको विश्वासको मतविरुद्ध एमाले संसदीय दलका नेता हिक्मतकुमार कार्कीले दिएको रिटमाथि न्यायाधीश सपना प्रधान मल्ल, डा. कुमार चुडाल र नहकुल सुवेदीको पूर्ण इजलासमा […]",
"content": "१८ भदौ, काठमाडौं । कोशी प्रदेशका मुख्यमन्त्री उद्धव थापाले पाएको विश्वासको मतमाथि उठेको विवादबारे सर्वोच्च अदालतमा सोमबार बहस सुरु भएको छ । विश्वासको मत लिने दिन प्रदेश सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेका इस्राइल मन्सुरीले दिएको विश्वासको मतविरुद्ध एमाले संसदीय दलका नेता हिक्मतकुमार कार्कीले दिएको रिटमाथि न्यायाधीश सपना प्रधान मल्ल, डा. कुमार चुडाल र नहकुल सुवेदीको पूर्ण इजलासमा सुनुवाइ सुरु भएको हो । सोमबार निवेदकको तर्फबाट बहस गर्दै कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले संविधान, कानुन, संसदीय व्यवस्था र सर्वोच्च अदालतले गरेको यसअघिको फैसलाविपरीत काम भएको भन्दै प्रदेशसभामा कुनै प्रस्तावमा मतदान हुँदा मत बराबर भएको अवस्थामा बाहेक सभाका अध्यक्षले मत दिन नसक्ने र दिए पनि मान्य नहुने जिकिर गरे । सोमबार दिनभर निवेदकको तर्फबाट कानुन व्यवसायीले बहस गर्ने भने सरकारी पक्षले मंगलबार पालो पाउनेछन् । सोमबारको सुनुवाइमा मुख्य गरी पाँचवटा विषयवस्तुलाई कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले प्राथमिकता दिए । कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले कोशी प्रदेशसभामा मुख्यमन्त्री उद्दव थापाले विश्वासको मत पाउन गरेको प्रस्तावमा बराबर मत व्यक्त नभएको र त्यो अवस्थामा सभाको अध्यक्षता गर्नेले मतदान गर्न नमिल्ने जिकिरलाई मुख्य रुपमा उठाए । निवेदक हिक्मत कार्कीको पक्षबाट बहस गर्ने सबैजसो कानून व्यवसायीहरुले संविधानमा नै बराबर मत व्यक्त भएको अवस्थामा बाहेक सभामुखले निर्णायक मत व्यक्त गर्न नपाउने भन्दै सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेका इस्राइल मन्सुरीले व्यक्त गरेको मत मान्य नहुने जिकिर गरे । वरिष्ठ अधिवक्ता टीकाराम भट्टराईले बहसका क्रममा भने, ‘कोशी प्रदेशको विषयमा मत बराबर भएको अवस्था थिएन । सभाको अध्यक्षता गर्ने व्यक्तिको हैसियत सभामुखको भन्दा बिल्कुल फरक हुदैन ।’ लिखित जवाफ पेश गर्ने क्रममा प्रदेश सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेका इस्राइल मन्सुरीले आफू सभामुख नभएको, केही समयका लागि मात्रै सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेकाले मत दिएको जिकिर गरेका थिए । उनले आफू प्रदेश सभाको सभामुख नभएकाले दुवैतिर मत बराबर नभएको अवस्थामा समेत मत दिन पाउने जिकिर गरेका थिए । त्यसको प्रतिवादमा कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले सभामुख र सभाको अध्यक्षता गर्ने व्यक्ति एउटै हुने भन्दै सभाध्यक्षलाई समेत निशर्त मतदान गर्ने अधिकार नभएको जिकिर गरे । सभाध्यक्षले समेत प्रदेश सभामा तटस्थता देखाउनुपर्ने र दुवैतर्फ बराबर मत भएमा मात्रै निर्णायक मत व्यक्त हुनुपर्नेमा इस्राइल मन्सुरीले पदको दुरुपयोग गरेको उनीहरुको जिकिर थियो । वरिष्ठ अधिवक्ता शम्भु थापाले भने, ‘सभामुख र सभा अध्यक्षको पद उस्तै हो, मतदान गर्न मिल्दैनथ्यो । दुवैले पदको दुरुपयोग गरे ।’ यसअघि तत्कालिन सभामुख बाबुराम गौतमले उद्धव थापालाई मुख्यमन्त्री बनाउने प्रस्तावमा हस्ताक्षर गर्दा एमाले नेता कार्कीले मुख्यमन्त्रीको नियुक्ति बदर गरी आफूलाई नियुक्त गर्न माग गरेका थिए । त्यस मुद्दामा ११ साउनमा फैसला सुनाउँदा तर सर्वोच्च अदालतले दुई वा त्यो भन्दा बढी दलको समर्थनमा सरकार बन्ने प्रक्रियालाई अघि बढ्न दिनुपर्ने औल्याएको थियो । यो पटक पनि कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले त्यही दावी दोहोर्‍याएका छन् । आफ्ना प्रतिस्पर्धी उद्धव थापाले विश्वासको मत नपाएको निश्चित भएको भन्दै कार्कीका कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले त्यस्तो अवस्थामा संविधानको धारा १६८(३) अनुसार प्रदेशसभामा सबैभन्दा बढी मत भएको दलको नेतालाई नै संसदीय दलको नेता बनाउनुपर्ने माग गरेका छन् । दोस्रो प्रतिनिधिसभा विघटनको मुद्दाको फैसलामा ‘विश्वासको मत नपाउनेलाई पटकपटक अवसर दिन मिल्दैन’ भन्ने व्याख्या भनेको भन्दै उनीहरुले अब पनि उद्धव थापाले अवसर पाउन नहुने र त्यो मौका हिक्मत कार्कीलाई जानुपर्ने तर्क गरे । कोशीका मुख्यमन्त्री उद्धव थापाले प्रदेशसभाका उपसभामुख र अरु जेष्ठ सदस्यहरुले बैठकमा उपस्थित नभएर गैरसंवैधानिक चरित्र देखाएको आरोप लगाएका थिए । लिखित जवाफ पेश गर्दै उनले आवश्यकताको सिद्धान्त अनुसार, सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेका मन्सुरले मतदान गरेको जिकिर गरेका थिए । कानुन व्यवसायीहरुले त्यो दावीको प्रतिवाद गरे । अनि सभको अध्यक्षता गरेका इस्राइल मन्सुरीले आफूलाई दलबाट पनि ह्विप आएकाले बाध्य भएर मतदान गरेको जिकिर गरे । वरिष्ठ अधिवक्ता रमेश बडालले भने, ‘उद्धव थापाज्यूलाई मुख्यमन्त्री बनिरहने रहर पूरा गर्न आवश्यकताको सिद्धान्तको दुरुपयोग गर्न मिल्दैन ।’ मुख्यमन्त्री थापाले विश्वासको मत लिने दिन सभाको अध्यक्षता गरेका इस्राइल मन्सुरीले मतदानको बेलामा मत दिएका थिएनन् । मतदान सकिएपछि सांसदहरुलाई मत सच्याउने समय दिएका बेला सभाको अध्यक्षता छाडेर उनले मत व्यक्त गरेका थिए । सोमबारको सुनुवाइका क्रममा न्यायाधीश सपना प्रधान मल्लले त्यसै विषयमा जिज्ञासा राखेकी हुन् । उनले भनिन्, ‘तपाईंहरु मत सच्याउने बेलामा मतदान भएको छ भन्नुहुन्छ । सुरुमै मतदान गर्ने हो कि मत सच्याउने बेलामा पनि मतदान गर्न मिल्छ ?’ जवाफमा वरिष्ठ अधिवक्ता रविनारायण खनालले भने, ‘एक त सभाका अध्यक्षले शर्तात्मक अवस्था बाहेक मत व्यक्त गर्न मिल्दैन, अरु बेलामा समेत मत सच्याउने बेलामा मतदान गर्ने परिकल्पनै हुदैन ।’",
"pubDate": "2023-09-04 15:58:58",
"image_url": null,
"source_id": "onlinekhabar",
"source_priority": 50136,
"country": [
"nepal"
],
"category": [
"top"
],
"language": "nepali"
}],
"nextPage": "1693836717610720005"
}
```

## Can anyone help me with this problem I am not able to resolve this problem

Comment: What is your actual API response JSON data? This error usually occurs when the JSON data received from the API does not match the expected data structure defined in the code

Comment: You need to edit you question and add the API response instead

Comment: I have tried your code and it works properly. I replaced Call by Response due to problem in Retrofit, but it was unrelated to the problem. Are you sure it was the response returned by the app? Maybe it returned something else?

Comment: `_newsItems.emit(response)` doesn't compile in my environment, which makes sense. `emit()` expects `List<NewsItem?>` while `response` is of type `Response<News!>`. Are you showing the real code? Or did I get something wrong with my imports?